# Can you clear the System Console without restarting Blender?

Tags: python, command-line

The question is simple enough, but I can't find the answer.
Is there an operator or something similar that clears the Blender System Console history?
I would also be willing to create an operator type script to "purge" the console.
It would be interesting to see if it's possible, or I'm just "delirious".
Restarting blender doesn't take long, but it would be nice to have a "Button" to do this.

Comment: Try printing a '\f' form feed and see what that does?

Comment: Forgive my ignorance, what should I enter? print ("\ f")?

Comment: Do print('\f') with no space. Its a control character like '\n' for newline

Comment: Ok I tried it from a Blender Text script and from Blender's python console. Weird symbols come up, but I don't really understand what this is for.

Comment: Just like `\n` `\t` and other text control stuff, where `\f` stand for form feed to indicate output go on next page. Which is not clear console for sure

Comment: @HikariTW, I'm really old. Form feed cleared the console on Amiga...

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Below is an example add-on that adds a button to the text editor for this purpose. Clearing the console is done with the platform specific commands `cls` for Windows and `clear` for Linux and macOS. Both are executed through [`os.system(command)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.system)

[image: Text Editor Header]

```
bl_info = {
    "name": "Clear System Console",
    "author": "Robert Guetzkow",
    "version": (1, 0, 0),
    "blender": (2, 81, 0),
    "location": "Text Editor Header",
    "description": "Clear the system console.",
    "wiki_url": "",
    "category": "Text Editor"}

import bpy
import os


class CLEARCONSOLE_OT_clear(bpy.types.Operator):
    bl_idname = "clearconsole.clear"
    bl_label = "Clear System Console"
    bl_description = "This operator clears the system console."
    bl_options = {"REGISTER"}

    def execute(self, context):
        if os.name == "nt":
            os.system("cls") 
        else:
            os.system("clear") 
        return {"FINISHED"}


def draw(self, context):
    self.layout.operator(CLEARCONSOLE_OT_clear.bl_idname)


classes = (CLEARCONSOLE_OT_clear,)


def register():
    for cls in classes:
        bpy.utils.register_class(cls)
        
    bpy.types.TEXT_HT_header.append(draw)


def unregister():
    bpy.types.TEXT_HT_header.remove(draw)
    
    for cls in classes:
        bpy.utils.unregister_class(cls)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```

Comment: I hadn't thought of other operating systems, as I use it on Windows, and I wanted to create a tools that simplifies my programming life a little. All clear, this answer did what I was looking for and more

Answer (score 13):

You can use `os.system` and call `cls` or `clear`:

- `os.system('cls')`
- `os.system('clear')`

sort of snippet:

```py
from os import system
cls = lambda: system('cls')

cls() #this function call will clear the console
```

Comment: Very clear and simple, it works wonders

Comment: Sorry, didn't see your answer until I was done implementing mine.

Comment: @RobertGützkow That's a nice spinet which should be archived at north pole!

Answer (score 7):

As of 2021, there is an operator for this.

1. Clear command history only:

```py
bpy.ops.console.clear(scrollback=False, history=True)
```

2. Clear command history **and** scrollback history:

```py
bpy.ops.console.clear(history=True)
```

3. Clear scrollback history only:

```py
bpy.ops.console.clear()
```

Reference: Blender's source code [here](https://github.com/blender/blender/blob/594f47ecd2d5367ca936cf6fc6ec8168c2b360d0/source/blender/editors/space_console/console_ops.c#L771).